# sem_wait() does not appear to actually be waiting. What might I be doing wrong?

Tags: c, multithreading, wait, semaphore

I am working on a project in which a "student" thread will use a semaphore to wake up a "TA" thread.

I have a semaphore called `studentNeedsHelp_Sem`

I initialize it with `sem_init(&studentNeedsHelp_Sem, 0 ,0);`

Before any of my student or TA threads are even created, I include these 3 lines:

```
printf("DEBUG WAITING\n");
sem_wait(&studentNeedsHelp_Sem);
printf("DEBUG DONE WAITING\n");
```

What **should** happen: `DEBUG WAITING` is printed, then we have to wait until a student actually needs help (and calls `sem_post(&studentNeedsHelp_Sem)` ) to see `DEBUG DONE WAITING`

What **is** happening: both are printed before my student threads even start.

(I am working in C on OSX, using POSIX pthreads)

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Where is 'studentNeedsHelp_Sem' declared?  No chance of it going away, is there?

Comment: @MartinJames It is declared globally very early in the file via the line `sem_t studentNeedsHelp_Sem;`

Comment: OK, well I had to ask, semaphores normally, well, work;)

Comment: I just booted up my Ubuntu virtual machine and everything works perfectly. What. Even.

Answer (score 3):

Check the return value of `sem_wait` (as you should ***always*** do whenever calling a library function or system call).  It's probably negative, indicating an error; look at `errno` or use `perror` to display the error.  I wouldn't be surprised if it's `EDEADLK`.

Indeed, if no threads have been started, then surely there is nobody to post the semaphore.  So `sem_wait` would never return at all.  This is a deadlock; your program is waiting for something that provably can never happen.  It may be that OSX's thread library detects this and has `sem_wait` return with an error, on the assumption that this isn't what you intended, and at least if `sem_wait` returns your program has a chance to recover.

Comment: Same for `sem_init` though. I recommend using `perror()`

Comment: You are right that `sem_wait` returns -1. Now it is a matter of why... I am aware that this causes deadlock, I was doing so on purpose to debug. But that is a good point, maybe the compiler saw the deadlock and ignored the wait call.

Comment: @MGriest: Not the compiler, but the thread library or the kernel code.  This is a run-time check, not compile-time.

Comment: Thank you. I added checks and it looks like my `sem_wait()` and `sem_post()` calls are failing throughout the program. Why might this be?

Comment: I'm not psychic; without seeing your code I have no idea.  But "it's failing" is only half the story - again, LOOK AT WHAT PERROR SAYS.

Comment: *LOOK AT WHAT PERROR SAYS*  Or at least emit the value of `errno`.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this question, as it turns out, MacOS does not support unnamed POSIX semaphores. A good alternative is named POSIX threads. They don't appear to differ much in their function besides initialization and destruction.

Instead of using sem_init, you can declare them with

```
sem_t *semaphore = sem_open("/semaphoreName", O_CREAT, 0644, 1);
```

You can read more about those parameters [here](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009696699/functions/sem_open.html).

You will use sem_wait and sem_post just as you would unnamed semaphores.

Instead of sem_destroy, you will use

```
sem_close(semaphore);
```

and then subsequently

```
sem_unlink("/semaphoreName");
```

This is all includes in the <semaphore.h> library just as unnamed semaphores are.

Hope this helps someone that is just as confused as I was.